# How to open in app browser for Googls Ads framework 6.12 for iOS

Tags: ios, admob

With Google's new ad framework 6.12 for iOS, all the ads default to open to safari instead of the in app browser.

Is there a way to get a delegate call back and show the ad in the in app browser rather than taking to safari.

Any help is appreciated.